# Textarea placeholder text

Tags: javascript, html, forms, placeholder

Struggling to understand why my placeholder in my textarea isnt showing yet the input is.

```
<textarea value="Begin your message..." onfocus="ClearPlaceHolder (this)" onblur="SetPlaceHolder (this)" class="contactForm" ></textarea>    

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ClearPlaceHolder (input) {
        if (input.value == input.defaultValue) {
            input.value = "";
        }
    }
    function SetPlaceHolder (input) {
        if (input.value == "") {
            input.value = input.defaultValue;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I tied replacing where it says input in this script but it dosnt change anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because [`textarea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) doesn't have the attribute `value`.
A `textarea`s value is between the opening and closing tags:

```
<textarea onfocus="ClearPlaceHolder(this)" 
          onblur="SetPlaceHolder(this)" 
          class="contactForm">Begin your message...</textarea>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SBSgE/)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use the HTML placeholder for this purpose?

```
<textarea placeholder="Please type something here..."></textarea>
```

I'd be more elegant in my opinion and it doesn't require any JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute `placeholder`:

```
<textarea placeholder="placeholder string"></textarea>
```

Comment: I cannot use html5 as the sites main audience are IE users. (older IE users sadly)

Answer (score 1):

Also remember that textarea doesn't have value **attribute** as you can read in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp
Value is a property so the statment you are using is correct for putting text in the text area

```
input.value = "text";
```

But remember that **creating and changing a value attribute doesn't change value property**.